# putting a scroll bar on a web page

Tags: html

I have a web page that is longer than the standard screen.  When I open it in the browser there is no vertical side scroll bar that allows the user to move down the page.  I tried using the line **overflow:scroll;** but it seems it is ignored.  I have a header and a line of buttons, then the content is in three sections. I have the **overflow:scroll** within the first BODY line like this: **body overflow:scroll class="plugin webkit chrome win Locale_en_US"**

How do I force the scroll bar to appear and where should it be properly placed?

Sorry, it's been years since I've done html or any kind of coding so bear with me.

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS in your post so people can see what's going on with your page.

Comment: <body style="overflow: scroll;" ...>

Comment: Dreamweaver put in a lot of crap so the html is long......

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow` is a css attribute, meaning that it should be in a `style` tag, or even better, in an external css file ( http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html )

In your case it would be:

```
<body style="overflow: scroll" class="plugin webkit chrome win Locale_en_US">
```

Comment: That did the trick...I have the scroll bar!!! I knew it was something simple.  My brain has been scrambled resolving another problem so wasn't viewing this clearly.  Thanks Jonas!

Answer (score 0):

Use css `style='overflow: auto;'`. If not works, find any element, that is `overflow: hidden;` and apply `overflow: auto` to it. Or add JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this in my project, i created a css like this

```
div.scrolled {
  width: 1150px;
  height: 620px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

and in my html file i only identify what area i want to introduce into my div and i do this

```
<body>
    <div class="scrolled">
      here goes wath you want
    </div>
</body>
```

and you will have your scroll in 'y' align, hope i helped you